# cannot workout vboxmange commands

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

hi guys I cannot get the hang of vboxmange commands can I get some help to understand the formatting better

```
C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox> VBoxManage.exe list vms
"mate" {e6d6f80c-826c-40f3-bf79-a4a8aded9c8b}
"windows crack" {2b0c0dba-dbf1-4716-81ce-5e2b0414d82e}
"windows crack Clone" {1e01c7b6-941a-4646-87b8-f2701a88b697}
"klin" {01d56e31-d85d-445c-b73e-da88859f3d0a}
"Kali-Linux-2020.1-vbox-amd64" {cc20fb4e-a9d5-4963-9f61-5c63f17470d2}

C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox> VBoxManage.exe debugvm {cc20fb4e-a9d5-4963-9f61-5c63f17470d2} "Kali-Linux-2020.1-vbox-amd64" log --debug
Oracle VM VirtualBox Command Line Management Interface Version 6.1.4
(C) 2005-2020 Oracle Corporation
All rights reserved.

VBoxManage.exe: error: Unknown subcommand: Kali-Linux-2020.1-vbox-amd64

Usage - Introspection and guest debugging:

  VBoxManage debugvm <uuid|vmname> dumpvmcore [--filename=name]

  VBoxManage debugvm <uuid|vmname> info <item> [args...]

  VBoxManage debugvm <uuid|vmname> injectnmi

  VBoxManage debugvm <uuid|vmname> log [--release | --debug] [group-settings...]

  VBoxManage debugvm <uuid|vmname> logdest [--release | --debug] [destinations...]

  VBoxManage debugvm <uuid|vmname> logflags [--release | --debug] [flags...]

  VBoxManage debugvm <uuid|vmname> osdetect

  VBoxManage debugvm <uuid|vmname> osinfo

  VBoxManage debugvm <uuid|vmname> osdmesg [--lines=lines]

  VBoxManage debugvm <uuid|vmname> getregisters [--cpu=id] [reg-set.reg-name...]

  VBoxManage debugvm <uuid|vmname> setregisters [--cpu=id] [reg-set.reg-name=value...]

  VBoxManage debugvm <uuid|vmname> show [--human-readable | --sh-export | --sh-eval | --cmd-set] [settings-item...]

  VBoxManage debugvm <uuid|vmname> stack [--cpu=id]

  VBoxManage debugvm <uuid|vmname> statistics [--reset] [--descriptions] [--pattern=pattern]

VBoxManage.exe: error: Unknown subcommand: Kali-Linux-2020.1-vbox-amd64

C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox> VBoxManage.exe debugvm {cc20fb4e-a9d5-4963-9f61-5c63f17470d2} | "Kali-Linux-2020.1-vbox-amd64" log --debug
'"Kali-Linux-2020.1-vbox-amd64"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox> VBoxManage.exe debugvm <{cc20fb4e-a9d5-4963-9f61-5c63f17470d2} | "Kali-Linux-2020.1-vbox-amd64"> log --debug
The system cannot find the file specified.

C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox> VBoxManage.exe debugvm <cc20fb4e-a9d5-4963-9f61-5c63f17470d2 | Kali-Linux-2020.1-vbox-amd64> osdetect
The system cannot find the file specified.

C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox> VBoxManage.exe debugvm <cc20fb4e-a9d5-4963-9f61-5c63f17470d2 | Kali-Linux-2020.1-vbox-amd64> osdetect > file.txt
The system cannot find the file specified.

C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox> VBoxManage.exe debugvm <cc20fb4e-a9d5-4963-9f61-5c63f17470d2 | Kali-Linux-2020.1-vbox-amd64> osdetect
The system cannot find the file specified.

C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox> VBoxManage.exe debugvm <cc20fb4e-a9d5-4963-9f61-5c63f17470d2 | Kali-Linux-2020.1-vbox-amd64> osinfo
The system cannot find the file specified.

C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox> VBoxManage.exe debugvm "Kali-Linux-2020.1-vbox-amd64" osinfo --filename file.txt
Oracle VM VirtualBox Command Line Management Interface Version 6.1.4
(C) 2005-2020 Oracle Corporation
All rights reserved.

VBoxManage.exe: error: Too many parameters

Usage:

  VBoxManage debugvm <uuid|vmname> osinfo

C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox> VBoxManage.exe debugvm <cc20fb4e-a9d5-4963-9f61-5c63f17470d2 | Kali-Linux-2020.1-vbox-amd64> osinfo --filename file.txt
The system cannot find the file specified.

C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox> VBoxManage.exe debugvm <cc20fb4e-a9d5-4963-9f61-5c63f17470d2 | Kali-Linux-2020.1-vbox-amd64> osinfo --filename >  file.txt
The system cannot find the file specified.

C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox> VBoxManage.exe debugvm <cc20fb4e-a9d5-4963-9f61-5c63f17470d2 | Kali-Linux-2020.1-vbox-amd64> osinfo
The system cannot find the file specified.

C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<…>` or `[…]` only indicate a required or optional parameter, not literal brackets.

The pipe sign `|` means "or", so `<uuid|vmname>` means you have to specify either the UUID *or* the name – the command does not need both.

For example:

```
VBoxManage debugvm {cc20fb4e-a9d5-4963-9f61-5c63f17470d2} log --debug
```

```
VBoxManage debugvm "Kali-Linux-2020.1-vbox-amd64" log --debug
```